# API Level for Google Maps Interactive Polylines?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

I use interactive Polylines to highlight calculated routes from Google Maps:

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) I get a base64 String which I then fed to:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(stringPolyline)) {
    List<LatLng> latLngList = PolyUtil.decode(stringPolyline);

    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polylineOptions.addAll(latLngList);
    polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);

    Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

On my devices with Android 6 & 7 it works perfectly. But I have a device with **Android 4.4.4** for an example. There I don't see those very same polylines.

**How can I make the polylines visible on my Android 4.4 devices?**

Comment: Have you tried adding a `width`to the polylineOptions? `polylineOptions.width(8)`

Comment: Yes, no changes :(

Comment: Weird...and have you debugged the app double checking `googleMap != null && latLngList.size() > 1` when you're adding polyline to map?

Comment: Debugging is same on both devices, the stringPolyline has a valid String with up to 40 characters ..

Comment: Rather than using polylineOptions.addAll , Try iterating latLngList using a loop and see if it completes the whole loop or not

Comment: Try to set zIndex of polyline and check visibility of polyline.

Comment: Two things. First, in the Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility "note that the first and last locations must be Level 3 points, otherwise, the polyline won't display on all levels". Secondly, how are you encoding the locations in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using one single polyline with multiple locations, try to paint several lines:

```
List<LatLng> latLngList = PolyUtil.decode(stringPolyline);

if (googleMap != null && latLngList.size() > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < latLngList .size() - 1; i++) {
        LatLng src = latLngList.get(i);
        LatLng dest = latLngList.get(i + 1);

        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(
            new PolylineOptions().add(
                new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
            ).width(5).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true)
        );
    }
}
```